# My IDE (Spring Tools Suite) shows invalid location of tag(a)?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
<div class="gifs container">
        <div class="row">
            <div th:each="gif : ${gifs}" class="col s12 l4">
                <a th:href="@{'/gif/' + ${gif.name}}">
                    <img th:src="@{'/gifs/' + ${gif.name} + '.gif'}" />
                  The problem occur in this line.  <a href="#" th:class="(${gif.favorite} ? 'un' : '') + 'mark favorite'"></a>

                 </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use Spring Tools Suite IDE. I also use Thymeleaf with Spring. Thanks.

Comment: Because you use `th:class` in your code and `th` is a namespace you did not define.

Comment: You have a link inside a link, that isn't allowed.